# What's the correct way to implement operator ++ for value-types?

Tags: c#, struct, operator-overloading, operators, increment

I'm working on a custom implementation of a Number struct, with very different ways of storing and manipulating numeric values.

The struct is fully immutable - all fields are implemented as `readonly`

I'm trying to implement the `++` and `--` operators, and I've run into a little confusion:
How do you perform the assignment?
Or does the platform handle this automatically, and I just need to return `n + 1`?

```
public struct Number
{
    // ...
    // ... readonly fields and properties ...
    // ... other implementations ...
    // ...

    // Empty placeholder + operator, since the actual method of addition is not important.
    public static Number operator +(Number n, int value)
    {
        // Perform addition and return sum
        // The Number struct is immutable, so this technically returns a new Number value.
    }

    // ERROR here: "ref and out are not valid in this context"
    public static Number operator ++(ref Number n)
    {
        // ref seems to be required,
        // otherwise this assignment doesn't affect the original variable?
        n = n + 1;
        return n;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I think this is not a duplicate of other questions about increment and decrement operators, since this involves value-types which behave differently than classes in this context. I understand similar rules apply regarding `++` and `--`, but I believe the context of this question is different enough, and nuanced enough, to stand on its own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement pre and post-increment / decrement operator in my class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282619/how-to-implement-pre-and-post-increment-decrement-operator-in-my-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The struct is fully immutable - all fields are implemented as `readonly`

Good!

> I'm trying to implement the `++` and `--` operators, and I've run into a little confusion: How do you perform the assignment?

You don't. Remember what the `++` operator does. Whether it is prefix or postfix it:

- fetches the original value of the operand
- computes the value of the successor
- stores the successor
- produces either the original value or the successor

The only part of that process that the C# compiler does not know how to do for your type is "compute the successor", so that's what your overridden `++` operator should do.  Just return the successor; let the compiler deal with figuring out how to make the assignment.

> Or does the platform handle this automatically, and I just need to return `n + 1`?

Yes, do that.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `num++;` by itself expands to `num = PlusPlusOperator(num);`. Since your data type is immutable, just `return n+1;` and the compiler will handle the rest.

Comment: Your first sentence is inaccurate.  The return value of `num++` is the original value, not the return value of `PlusPlusOperator(num)`.  The lazy oversimplification (which is still inaccurate) is to claim that `num++` returns the value before performing the increment.  See [Eric Lippert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34342756/18192) for the accurate answer.  Eric Lippert goes into more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/18192).  Be warned that the accepted answer to that question is wrong.

Comment: @Brian: No, the first sentence is accurate though I see why you think it isn't., The sentence states that the **statement** `num++;` is an assignment of the increment operator result to the original variable, which it is. Had SaxxonPike said that the **expression** `num++` was simply that, that would be wrong.  But the compiler is perfectly within its rights to generate the statement form as though it were simply an assignment because the value -- the original value of the variable -- is discarded. That said, I agree that this answer is misleading; that semi is subtle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my answer to be more clear. "Statement" is the word I should have used.

Answer (score 1):

The processing of `++` and `--` operators is described in C# language specification, section 7.7.5 Prefix increment and decrement operators:

> The run-time processing of a prefix increment or decrement operation of the form ++x or --x consists of the following steps:
>
> • If x is classified as a variable:
>
> o x is evaluated to produce the variable.
>
> o The selected operator is invoked with the value of x as its argument.
>
> o The value returned by the operator is stored in the location given by the evaluation of x.
>
> o The value returned by the operator becomes the result of the operation.

So a custom overloads of these operators only need to produce an incremented/decremented value. The rest is handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

A Number class is going to have a value of some kind as a property.

```
public static Number operator ++(Number n)
{
    // ref seems to be required,
    // otherwise this assignment doesn't affect the original variable?
    n.value = n.value + 1;
    return n;
}
```

This should do what you want.

I wrote this using your struc and added the value property.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new Number();
    x.value = 3;
    x++;
    Console.WriteLine(x.value);
    Console.Read();
}
```

This properly generates a 4

Comment: You missed one detail, the struct is immutable, so you can't assign the value field like that. :)